# How to make Jupyterlab or Jupyter show source code in a popup window?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Writing in the below

```
sqlContext.sql?
```

or pressing Shift+TAB while cursor is in the 'sql' of sqlContext.sql will make it popup the docstring of it.  Writing in the below will show the source code and the docstring.

```
sqlContext.sql??
```

Is there any hotkey for this? I dont wanna keep writing in 'something??' every time I want to see the sourcecode.